# C# slicing/assigning variables

Tags: c#, slice

```
        String input;
        Console.WriteLine(":>");
        input = (Console.ReadLine());

        string[] column = input.Split(' ');
        int number_of_elements = column.Count(s => s != null);//counts the number of elements inputted

if (number_of_elements > 7 && column[0].ToLower() == "add") {
            **String firstName = column[1, number_of_elements-6];**
            String lastName = column[number_of_elements-5];
            String id_Clause = column[number_of_elements-4];
            String id_Number = column[number_of_elements-3];
            String as_Clause = column[number_of_elements-2];
            String as_Level = column[number_of_elements-1];

        }
```

I am trying to make a C# program that takes values like this

```
ADD Mary Jane Watson ID 123456 AS Advanced
```

I am trying to make

```
            String firstName = Mary Jane;
            String lastName = Watson;
            String id_Clause = ID
            String id_Number = 123456
            String as_Clause = AS
            String as_Level = Advanced
```

THe last name Watson but everything between ADD and Watson as First Name.

So if the input was

```
ADD Mary Jane Jennifer Watson ID 123456 AS Advanced
```

then the result would be

```
            String firstName = Mary Jane Jennifer;
            String lastName = Watson;
            String id_Clause = ID
            String id_Number = 123456
            String as_Clause = AS
            String as_Level = Advanced
```

Comment: What if you have a LastName composed of two parts? IE _MAC DONALD_?

Comment: Side note - if you only want to work with non-null elements, you'd do better to filter them out once and work with the filtered list. As it is, there may be, say, 8 non-null elements but you're not guaranteed that, say, `number_of_elements - 3` will access a non-null element.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Something like:

```
firstName = String.Join(" ", column, 1, number_of_elements - 6);
```

Comment: They want to skip `column[0]` since we've already established that it's the word `add` and not part of the first name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .split(' ') but since you don't know the actual length of the name and you don't have any other delimiters this is difficult.

some things you could do:

```
      String[] splitValues = "ADD Mary Jane Watson ID 123456 AS Advanced".Split(' ');

      String lastName = splitValues[splitValues.Length-5]
      String id_Clause = splitValues[splitValues.Length-4]
      String id_Number = splitValues[splitValues.Length-3]
      String as_Clause = splitValues[splitValues.Length-2]
      String as_Level = splitValues[splitValues.Length-1]
```

and for the first name take the remaining values, skipping the first. which is the ADD.

This is just an example, but i hope you get the point. Also, it doesn't cover the cases where the last name is made from multiple pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of ID-token.

```
var s = input.Split(' ');
var indexID = Array.FindIndex(s, a => a == "ID");
```

To get the first names skip ADD-token and take 2 less than the index (to avoid the surname and the ID-token).

```
        string firstName = String.Join(" ", s.Skip(1).Take(indexID - 2));
```

Similarly use the index to get the last name and the idNumber

```
        string lastName = s[indexID - 1];
        string idNumber = s[indexID + 1];
```

The level is the last entry in the array.

```
        string asLevel = s[s.Length - 1];
```

Below is a full sample program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = new string[] { "ADD Mary Jane Watson ID 123456 AS Advanced", "ADD Mary Jane Jennifer Watson ID 123456 AS Advanced" };

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Extract(input).ToString());
            }
        }

        private static Person Extract(string input)
        {
            var s = input.Split(' ');

            var indexID = Array.FindIndex(s, a => a == "ID");

            string firstName = String.Join(" ", s.Skip(1).Take(indexID - 2));
            string lastName = s[indexID - 1];
            string idNumber = s[indexID + 1];
            string asLevel = s[s.Length - 1];

            return new Person()
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                IDNumber = idNumber,
                ASLevel = asLevel
            };
        }


    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string IDNumber { get; set; }
        public string ASLevel { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + IDNumber + " " + ASLevel;
        }
    }
```